# "mail" command works while in a bash script, but command is not found when using it in the CLI

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I have postfix installed in my Linux machine as a send-only mail server and works great when I use the "sendmail" command. Recently I created an executable bash script to run as a daemon and within the script I use the command "mail" instead of "sendmail", and to ym surprise, it was able to send emails without any errors whe the script it is run. However, when I want to use the "mail" command in the command line, for testing purposes", I get the following error:

```
Command 'mail' not found, but can be installed with:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          sudo apt install mailutils
```

How is it possible that "mail" works without any errors from within simple bash script, but fails to work in the cli because apparently mailutils is not installed?

Comment: You've a different `$PATH` in the two places? Or you've defined a function `mail()` somewhere? If it works in your script, try `type mail` also in your script and report back what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that crontab, where my script was being run from, was sending mails bc of the MAILTO line and the stderr. The command "mail" was probably never  working.